# how to access MySql database of web hosting site

Tags: php, web-hosting

I have created my own web site in PHP. I have member login function also. For login function i have to create a table of member info in **the database of web hosting company(my hosting is provided by GoDaddy.com)** and then access mySql database.

**>> how can I create the table in my hosting server??**

my current code is--

```
<?php 
$host="localhost"; // Host name **??what will be my host??**   
$username=""; // Mysql username  
$password=""; // Mysql password  
$db_name="test"; // Database name  
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse. 
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");  
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

Answer (score 1):

The hosting provider should give you that information. There is no way for us to know.

Answer (score 1):

To set up a database for your website with GoDaddy.com, you have to:

1. Log in to your `Account Manager`.
2. Click `Web Hosting`.

Then you can create your MySQL database.

It then takes up to 1 hour for the database to be created.

Once the database is created, you can click `Actions` and then `Details` to find more information, such as its host name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think the OP (the person who asked the question) is also after a way of creating a new table on their existing GoDaddy.com MySQL database. Could you expand your answer to include how to do this though Account Manager, if possible? Alternatively, you can use comments to ask for clarification from the OP.