# Website connected to local database, how to make it remote access?

Tags: mysql, database, host

I have created a website that is hosted. The database it uses is connected locally. I created the database in MySQL workbench. How can I "host" this database remotely so that when using the website it can be accessed from any machine? Thanks

Comment: I guess you are using a connection string, instead of pointing to a localhost database point to a server using a public ip address. You also need to be sure to have your firewall and router settings according to connect from outside of your network or wherever the server is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to access MySql database of web hosting site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801005/how-to-access-mysql-database-of-web-hosting-site)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is whether or not your hosting supports MySQL (which many do).

If it does, create a database there, export your schema using MySQL Workbench and then import it into your new database using whatever import function your hosting provides (e.g. via PHPMyAdmin).

Then change your code to connect to your new database on localhost when it runs on the hosting server (note that there may be limitations on what you can call the database).

Otherwise you will have to do what @BrankVictoria suggests in their comment - much harder. To be honest if there's no MySQL support I'd be thinking about changing my hosting.